# Segregating columns based on ID column

Tags: mysql

Based on a ID column I need to segregate data. I've a table,

```
ID  Course  Seats
1   CS      50
1   EC      60
1   ME      30
2   CS      60
2   EC      40
2   ME      25
2   EE      20
```

Basically, need result set in the below form, where Seats column is based on the ID of the above table.

```
Course Seats_ID = 1 Seats_ID = 2
CS      50              60
EC      60              40
ME      30              25
EE      NULL            20
```

Please advise how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not have a *pivot* function which is essentially what you need to do.  In order to rotate the data, you will use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to turn the data from rows into columns:

```
select Course,
  max(case when id=1 then seats end) Seats1,
  max(case when id=2 then seats end) Seats2
from yourtable
group by course
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1364/1)

This gives the result:

```
| COURSE | SEATS1 | SEATS2 |
----------------------------
|     CS |     50 |     60 |
|     EC |     60 |     40 |
|     EE | (null) |     20 |
|     ME |     30 |     25 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional aggregation:

```
select course,
       sum(case when id = 1 then seats end) as Seats_1,
       sum(case when id = 2 then seats end) as Seats_2
from t
group by course;
```